# how to accept 2 or more words in regex

Tags: regex, validation

how can i add more than two conditions in my regex?

what should i put for my regex to accept other words?
i need to accept then as a whole so that i can pass the value to the other page

ex: also accept

```
contact2012,service2012,docs2014
```

regex

```
    "pas":{             
    "regex":"/service2012/",
    "alertText":"* Invalid Password"},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with following regex:

```
/contact2012|service2012|docs2014/
```

It will matches strings that contain any of your keyword separated with `|`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want alternatives.
Alternatives are separated with | (pipe). In most cases you also want to surround it with brackets: (Foo|Bar)